# How to resolve the cx_freeze Error : _ and_ are the same file?

Tags: python, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I was trying to convert my pyqt5 application to exe. I was using cx_freeze for doing so. I created setup.py file just as cx_freeze requires and ran `python setup.py build` command to generate the exe. It seems there is some error during the build phase as shown.
Error shown:

```
creating directory build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib
copying data from package PyQt5...
copying Z:\translator\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd
copying C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python3.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib\PyQt5\python3.dll
copying Z:\translator\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\bin\Qt5Core.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib\PyQt5\Qt5Core.dll
copying Z:\translator\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtGui.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib\PyQt5\QtGui.pyd
copying Z:\translator\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\bin\Qt5Gui.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib\PyQt5\Qt5Gui.dll
copying Z:\translator\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib\PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd
error: WindowsPath('Z:/translator/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.pyd') and WindowsPath('build/exe.win-amd64-3.9/lib/PyQt5/QtWidgets.pyd') are the same file.
```

cx_freeze copies the QtWidget.pyd file from virtual environment and then raises both file are same error. How can resolve this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

uninstall what you were running first

then check on `WindowsPath('build/exe.win-amd64-3.9/lib/PyQt5/QtWidgets.pyd')` already exists in the filepath that is exactly the same.

I think it could be living around here in the filesystem
`\src\Application\build/exe.win-amd64-3.9/lib/PyQt5/QtWidgets.pyd`

if it exists delete that file and reinstall

Comment: I tried deleting the whole build folder before retrying, it is not working. ```copying Z:\translator\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib\PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd
error: WindowsPath('Z:/translator/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.pyd') and WindowsPath('build/exe.win-amd64-3.9/lib/PyQt5/QtWidgets.pyd') are the same file.``` This shows that cx_freeze first copies the file and then raises the error.

Comment: what command did you originally run?

Comment: i ran : ```python setup.py build```

Comment: what did you run to delete to folder? You're welcome to edit you post above to have all the info in one area

Comment: I edited the post. I deleted the build folder just as we delete any other folder in windows.

Comment: When you ran the command to delete the folder. Did you get a confirmation that it no longer existed? Or did you just run whatever command you ran

@RishabhGupta try python setup.py --verbose build

Comment: @RishabhGupta did you run the shell as administrator? To me it seems like the file is getting in the way unless you can give more data.

Comment: Yeah i tried running the cmd as administrator. Yes the folder gets deleted i confirm it before running the command again. What else exactly do you want to know?